# FOL-Interpretation of a tableaux

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose I have the FOL-Formula $F := \forall x \exists y. R(x, y)$ in negation normal form. Now I want to show that $F$ is satisfiable using the tableaux calculus (TC1).

By application of rules I get the completed and clash-free tableaux:

$$\forall x \exists y. R(x, y)$$
$$|$$
$$\exists y. R(t, y)$$
$$|$$
$$R(t, a)$$

Clearly, $F$ is satisfiable. But how would I go about constructing am model from the tableaux?

I see two approaches:

1. The domain is $D=\{a, t\}$ and the extension of $R$ is $I(R) = \{(t, a)\}$. But this is clearly not a model of $F$.
2. The domain is $D=\{a\}$, the extension of $R$ is $I(R) = \{(t, a)\}$ and $t$ is treated as 0-ary function symbol with $I(t) = a$.

I am not confident with any of those approaches and be very happy about some help :)

Comment: The issue is that the formula has models of every number of elements. With $D = \{ a \}$ - as you said - it is enough to have $R^I = \{ (a,a) \}$, but we can use also $D = \{ a_0, a_1, \ldots \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you 'instantiated' the universal, you used a $t$, but when instantiating the existential, you used $a$.  This is an important difference:  the $a$ is an individual constant: it refers to a specific object.  The $t$, however, works more like a variable. Indeed, if $t$ were a constant, then just because we can satisfy $\exists y . R(t,y)$ does not mean that we have satisfied $\forall x \ \exists y . R(x,y)$

So, I assume that there is some rule in the system you are using ('TC1') that says that you should always make sure to instantiate the $t$ with any constant that occurs in the same branch that it occurs in.

The upshot is that you should not treat $t$ as a specific object of your domain. That is, it makes little sense to use a domain of $\{ a,t\}$. Thus, your option $1$ is out.  Likewise, your option $2$ does not work, since if you say that  $I(R)= \{ (t,a) \}$, you are still treating $t$ as a specific object.

What *does* work, however, is to say that your domain is $\{a\}$, and that $I(R)=\{ (a,a) \}$.